# Row was updated or deleted by another transaction while rendering

Tags: jquery, grails, asynchronous, wait, gsp

I having a project structure like two admin can view a single patients details, so when both the admin is looking for the same patient detail(consider as health condition) at the same time. I getting the exception like

```
Row was updated or deleted by another transaction
```

After debuging, in the `controller` side there is no problem, but in the `gsp` there is one `service call` that delays the rendering process of gsp, so automatically at the same time when another admin is trying to render the same gsp this exception will rise.

Note 1: I can't able to avoid that service call from gsp.

Note 2: There is no save or update operation - so solutions like merge() or lock() will work hardly

**My Question**: Is there any way to make that request to wait until this render process is over? or any other way to avoid this exception.

**code snippet**

```
def test = testService.getAllLogs(id, startDate, endDate)
render(view:"test",model:[test: test])
```

Comment: Is the service method marked as READ_ONLY for the transaction? That would be a good way to avoid this.

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is truly happening because of a view action and no edits you probably have something making modifications and grails is trying to auto save for you.

Look for sorting of lists on domain objects in your gsp or controller that will cause an update when nothing has really changed. You can also look in the db and see if the version column is being updated on page view.

Now if the true problem is that edits are happening in multiple places you have a few options. Break up the domain model more fine grained to limited collisions of edits. Or make sure to push all changes back from the server to live pages.